# what is the best approach to detect small objects with similar shape?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I'm working a model which detect different products in supermarket shelf. In the training data, there are a lot of objects with similar shape placed very close to or stacked to each others.(eg: milks with different brands are stacked, placed on the same shelf, the model should be able to detect milk1, milk2). What is the best approach to this problem. I've tried to train a Faster RCNN, but the RPN isn't  working well. I've also tried feature matching, but it cannot detect partially visible objects. Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

The training images look like this

Link to FRCNN result when detect 2 type of milk and 1 type of yogurt

[faster r-cnn detection result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kNF3NiU22lcifwRp8N3RhyGOVq6WiGmw)

Comment: The text in images is clear? Can't you extract some data from them?

Comment: I just added some training sample. Would it work better if the input images in higher resolution?

Comment: Another question, Is the position of the camera is same for objects with same shape and different size?

Comment: yes, all object are observed in the same distance

Comment: @alirezazolanvari I just added the link to detection result using faster r-cnn

Comment: Thanks. So, the relative height and the relative width of the objects can be extracted from the images. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. You're correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all objects are observed in the same distance and almost same angle, the relative height and width can be helpful features for recognizing objects with similar shape and different size. By this features different methods like GAN algorithms such as CoGAN and BiGAN may help you in this problem.

It should be noticed that for recognizing the size of the objects the features play more important role than the algorithms.

Comment: I've always thought that GAN is used for generation. Do you have any link about applying GAN for object detection? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: What do you think if I used relative width and height as output for RPN instead of bounding box coordinates

Comment: When you can generate an entity well, obviously you can detect it accurately. In well-trained GAN networks, the discriminative network is powerful enough for recognizing generated entities. So, after you GAN had been trained, you can use the trained discriminative network for solving your problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you suggest that discriminator can be used to classify objects in my problem for better accuracy. What do you think I should do to improve my RPN accuracy?

Comment: I think giving the presented features (height and width) beside the images can improve the accuracy

Comment: Okay. I will try them out and update the result. Thank a lot

Comment: If the answer is good to you upvote and accept it ;)

Comment: I upvoted but nothing happened cause I'm below 15 rep :D

Comment: it's ok. This action is generally for helping others with the same question